# Why is my Scanner taking too long to convert inputs to a 2D char array?

Tags: java, arrays, grid, java.util.scanner, variable-assignment

## Scanner to 2D char array taking too long time.

Hi! For some reason unkown to me makes my code take very long time, my only guess is that Scanner is slow however I cant escape it because I need to use it. The size of the seaCard can be anything from 1 * 1 to 10000 * 10000. The cpu time limit is 8 seconds which should be plenty of time to execute this. The whole assignment is to count islands in a grid but I cant even read the data in a timely manner.

The inputs are maps like these

```
~~~~~
~@@~~
@~~~~.
```

My code is like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = input.nextInt();
        int cols = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        
        char[][] seaCard = new char[rows][cols];

        // making the map
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            String thisRow = input.nextLine();
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                seaCard[i][j] = thisRow.charAt(j);
            }
        }
        input.close();
```

I have tried changing from 2D array to a 1D string array but that didnt change much, I have also tried using next() instead of nextLine().

I expected the code to run smoothly and not take longer than 6s for rows = 10000 and cols = 10000 with an string input of a 10000 string lines of length 10000.

However it just dosent finish, my only idea is that because Im using 2 for loops I get a time complexity of n^2 but I feel like this still shouldnt make it take this long.

Comment: I just noticed that some part of the text as well as input got into the code area, I apolagize its been a long time since I did this ^^.

Comment: Why don't your sprinkle some print statements in key locations to see what is going on?

Comment: Does it work with smaller dimensions?

Comment: I just did and I can see that it is doing what I want it to but its just very slow. Am I missing something?

Comment: It does work without issues for smaller dimensions

Comment: Yes. From what I have heard from other classmates that have passed this assignment they have used the same method of typing everything into the console.

Comment: I print every nextLine and it is slow. It prints done when it is done and the info I get is total time 42s. I am unsure how to fix it because I need to get the grid from somewhere so it can be used for grading.

Comment: If this is from a coding challenge / practice site, please include a link to the problem page.

Comment: it is from my school so I dont think anyone outside the school can access the exercise :/ sorry

Comment: That is all to my code, I havent added in anything more yet because this takes so long for me.

Comment: Windows 11 on this pc and I have tried it on another pc I have that has windows 10

Comment: @Jock, If you are storing files that are `10,000` chars by `10,000` chars,  that's a total of `200,000,000 bytes`, or `200 MB`.  That's too much for a map; in my opinion.

Comment: @Jock, since your map data is simply a `~` or `@`, have you tried using a run-length encoding?

Comment: I have not tried run-length encoding. Gonna start reading up on it now.

Comment: The assignment reads like this, You are gonna write a program that counts islands, an island is atleast one @ if they are neighbors they are part of the same island. All inputfile start with two numbers x and y where x is how many rows and y is how many columns there are. You can assume that both x and y is larger or equal to 1 and can get as big as 10000. You can also expect all islands filled in so no water can be in the middle of an island. Output is a number of how many islands.

Comment: You've got to be a fast typist. Not sure how many hours it would take *me* to enter 10,000 lines of text...

Comment: Well I have examples which I can just copy into the console, Ofc Im not typing it manually

Comment: OK. 1000x1000 is instantaneous for me, reading not from clipboard, but stdin (from a file)

Comment: It would be a good idea to move the description of the assignment from comments to the question body.  Also,  if two `@` are in diagonally adjacent, are they part of the same island, that is neighbors?

Comment: Off-topic: You can put your input into a file, and use input redirection to have your program read from the file.

Comment: (1) Are you sure it is the input part of the program that is slow, and not something that comes after the part you've shown?  (2) Are you running the program from within an IDE or from a command console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version takes input from a file. The first line should be the number of rows.  Nothing needs to be entered from the console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner fromFile = new Scanner(new File("C:/yourFilename.txt"))) {
        int rows = fromFile.nextInt(); // read the rows from the file.
        fromFile.nextLine();  // remove EOL from the input buffer
        char[][] seaCard = new char[rows][];
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            seaCard[r] = fromFile.nextLine().toCharArray();
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to enter the columns.   Just type in the number of rows and then type each input string of any length.  It will adjust the columns accordingly.  This will be what is known as a ragged array where each row can be of different number of columns.

Comment: What "card" are you talking about? Your code indicates you're taking input from the console.

Comment: It works very well, Thanks alot. I do beleive that alot of the issue is on my pc but reading from a file works wonders!

Comment: @Jock I modified my answer.  I was too focused on your console input.  If you can edit the file,  just put the number of rows as the first line.  Then all input can be taken from the file.